# Counting members with certain roles in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So I'm trying to make a command to show the number on members using a certain role (the role should be defined by the message (so I don't have to make a script for just 1 role, with roleid)) but it seems to not work at all, so maybe some advice? I'm new to programming, and using API doesn't give me much really :) The ideal setup is to have a system, which can show either information about all roles, or just 1 role, which you define through message.

So what I've tried is:

```
async def rolescount(ctx):
  def check(message):
    return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel
    
  await ctx.send('Waiting for role')
  
  message = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
  role = ctx.get_role_name(message.content)
  role = ctx.guild.get_role(role.content)
  await ctx.send(len(role.members))
```

But it doesn't seem to work, when the bot is waiting for the message, he doesn't take any responses and just sits there, what am I doing wrong?

Also tried to find similar cases, nothing really, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@bot.command()
async def rolescount(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    await ctx.send(len(role.members))
```

Now you have use this command like this: `<PREXIX>rolescount @ROLE`
If you want to print all members with this role do:

```
@bot.command()
async def rolescount(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    for member in role.members:
        print(f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}")
```